# For $f(z)={1\over 2}({z+{1\over z}})$ find $f(D)$: $D=\{|z|=1,\Im(z)>0\}$,$D=\{|z|=1,\Im(z)<0\}$.

Tags: complex-analysis

For $f(z)={1\over 2}({z+{1\over z}})$ find $f(D)$: $D=\{|z|=1,\Im(z)>0\}$,$D=\{|z|=1,\Im(z)<0\}$.

For some reason, I get the for both: $f(D)=[-1,1]$, so what is the point here? I really try to understand what the point of this question is. I guess, therefore, that I must have done something wrong. I would appreciate and referance.

Comment: Clearly, $D=\{z:\lvert z\rvert=1,\Im(z)>1\}=\varnothing$ and $D=\{z:\lvert z\rvert=1,\Im(z)<1\}=\{z:\lvert z\rvert=1\}\setminus\{i\}$. Did you mean something else?

Comment: I am deeply sorry. It was meant to be $0$.

Comment: Joukowski mapping(used in applications] ,,the answer (-1,1) since f(z)=(z+z')/2 = Re(z) on the unit circle.Moreover, f(z)=f(z') there...[' denotes conjugation]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a special case of the Muskhelishvili transformation, applied on the upper half ($\Im(z)>0$) and the lower half ($\Im(z)<0$) of the unit circle.

In other words, for $z=e^{i\theta}$ it is:

$$f\left(e^{i\theta}\right)=\frac{1}{2}\cdot\left(e^{i\theta}+\frac{1}{e^{i\theta}}\right)$$

For $\theta=0$, $f(z)=1$, while for $\theta=\pi$, $f(z)=-1$.

On the other hand, doing some elementary trig calculations, $f(e^{i\theta})=\cos(\theta)$, so for $\theta\in[0,\pi/n]$ it is precisely the range $[\cos(\theta),1]$ and for $\theta\in[0,\pi]$ it is the range $[-1,1]$ [*].

When $\Im(z)<0$ the image of $f$ has the same range, since $\cos(-\theta)=\cos(\theta)$.

Below is a picture of for $\theta\in[0,\pi/5]$. The image of $f$ in this case is simply the projection of the circle's arc on the $x$-axis.

[*] Note that for your question the answer is $(-1,1)$ since $\Im(z)\neq 0$.

[image]